# WP query_posts() - Results ignore most recent post

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code (leaving out everything before and after to start with):

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=4' ); ?>
<?php
if ( have_posts() )
the_post();
?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s',     'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php twentyten_posted_on(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<p><?php printf( __( 'Posted in %2$s', 'twentyten' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', get_the_category_list( ', ' ) ); ?></p> 
<p><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyten' ), __( '1 Comment', 'twentyten' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></p>
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The resulting page doesn't show the 4 most recent posts - it is dropping the most recent post.  Here is the live page:

http://www.metricit.com/blog/

Here is another page (using the standard loop archive code) showing the 4 most recent posts.

http://www.metricit.com/category/blog/

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have this above your loop?

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() )
the_post();
?>
```

Get rid of it - that's skipping the first post.

Comment: I was basing my code loosely on the default archive code and it is in there.  This is my first time digging into custom themes and pages and WP and I'm still learning.  I'll look up what that block does.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you should remove the first call to `the_post()`, try changing your code to this:

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=4' ); ?> 
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?> 
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s',     'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php twentyten_posted_on(); ?> 
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<p><?php printf( __( 'Posted in %2$s', 'twentyten' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', get_the_category_list( ', ' ) ); ?></p>
<p><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyten' ),__( '1 Comment', 'twentyten' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></p> 
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>       
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Notice that I removed your first `the_post();` and added a `<?php endif; ?>` after the loop.

Comment: Basically same answer as above so I'm sure it works.  Thank you for responding so quickly.  I appreciate the help.